# ConfigurationErrorsException "Thread was being aborted" on Membership.Provider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Occasionally on app restart this error will occur:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException - System.Web, Thread was being aborted.     
(C:\Inetpub\web.config line 417) 
at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize() 
at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()
...
```

When it does the app needs to be restarted to clear the error, every page request after this raises the same bug.  Line 417 is the Membrship provider add line in web.config.  We're using the UpmMembershipProvider from MS Commerce Server, but it doesn't seem to be hitting this code, it's dying on the ConfigurationErrorsException inside `System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()` before it tried to instantiate the UpmMembershipProvider.  If it was an error inside UpmMembershipProvider I'd expect to see it inside the stacktrace.

What can cause `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException - System.Web, Thread was being aborted.` to be raised?

Comment: I've committed a fix to this problem. Continued discussion of the issue will be here: https://github.com/YAFNET/YAFNET/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

Is the configuration by any chance redirecting the response?
Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect can cause a ThreadAbortedException.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that a redirect could occur, and it only seems to happen on app restart